# Need help on oracle query

Tags: oracle

I have two oracle tables, table 1 contains students info and the second table contains student transaction details. Now I want an sql query to bring out the report of the transaction details for each student. eg student ID, name, amount, transaction date etc.
Note, a student can have many transactions, so I want a situation where by if student with ID 1 bought 3 items, in the result of the query I want to see student ID 1 and the sum of 3 items bought.
I don't want the student ID to repeat 3 times and the number of items bought.

Thanks

**EDIT**:

Here's the query I have so far:

```
select 
    distinct(s.spriden_id), 
    s.spriden_last_name, 
    s.spriden_first_name, 
    t.tbraccd_detail_code, 
    t.sum(tbraccd_amount), 
    t.tbraccd_term_code,
    t.tbraccd_user, 
    t.TBRACCD_DATE 
from SPRIDEN s, TBRACCD t 
where s.spriden_pidm = t.tbraccd_pidm 
and t.tbraccd_term_code = 201320 
and t.tbraccd_desc = 'Misc Book Store Charges';
```

(The first table is SPRIDEN while the second table is TBRACCD)

Comment: Post table definitions, post sample data, post the expected results.

Comment: I think, you can do it using a SELECT statement, but is kinda hard without any table info.. You are basically asking to do it from scratch for you?

Comment: No, this is the script i have written, but the query is not summing and keep repeating student id with repetitive transactions.

Comment: see the script here: select distinct(s.spriden_id), s.spriden_last_name, s.spriden_first_name, t.tbraccd_detail_code, t.sum(tbraccd_amount),
t.tbraccd_term_code, t.tbraccd_user, t.TBRACCD_DATE from SPRIDEN s, TBRACCD t where
s.spriden_pidm = t.tbraccd_pidm and t.tbraccd_term_code = 201320 and t.tbraccd_desc = 'Misc Book Store Charges';

Comment: The first table is SPRIDEN while the second table is TBRACCD

Comment: Ok, now post sample data for `SPRIDEN` and `TBRACCD`, as well as expected results for you query given the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY to group students, as below:

```
select 
    s.spriden_id, 
    sum(t.tbraccd_amount), 
from SPRIDEN s, TBRACCD t 
where s.spriden_pidm = t.tbraccd_pidm 
and t.tbraccd_term_code = 201320 
and t.tbraccd_desc = 'Misc Book Store Charges'
GROUP BY s.spriden_id;
```

MODIFIED VERSION to select all columns:

```
select 
    s.spriden_id, 
    t.tbraccd_entry_date, 
    t.tbraccd_term_code, 
    t.tbraccd_user,
    sum(t.tbraccd_amount)
from SPRIDEN s, TBRACCD t 
where s.spriden_pidm = t.tbraccd_pidm 
and t.tbraccd_term_code = 201320 
and t.tbraccd_desc = 'Misc Book Store Charges'
GROUP BY 
    s.spriden_id,
    t.tbraccd_entry_date, 
    t.tbraccd_term_code, 
    t.tbraccd_user;
```

Comment: Hello, when I ran the above query I got an error message t.sum: invalid identifier!

Comment: I corrected the sum function. The table alias (t.) needs to be inside the sum function.

Comment: Thank you very much but when i run this query I got an error message: NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION!

Comment: This is the query that gave NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION MESSAGE! select s.spriden_id,tbraccd_entry_date, tbraccd_term_code,tbraccd_user,sum(t.tbraccd_amount) 
from SPRIDEN s, TBRACCD t 
where s.spriden_pidm = t.tbraccd_pidm 
and t.tbraccd_term_code = 201320 
and t.tbraccd_desc = 'Misc Book Store Charges'
GROUP BY s.spriden_id;

Comment: You have to include all the columns that you want to SELECT in the GROUP BY clause as well. See the modified version above in the answer.